# table content out of the border of table td

Tags: html, css

I want to set border width on td. But I do not know why the width of  is out of the table?
here is the demo of my problem:http://jsfiddle.net/GreatFusion/humg4/2/

I just want to make the inner table part to be blue.However it is confused that the out side of table is also be blue?
Here is the html code:

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td style="border-left:10px solid blue">Content</td>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td>Content</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td>Content</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td>Content</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Here is the CSS code:

```
table {
  border:1px solid #000;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0; 
}
tr {border-top:1px solid #000;}
tr + tr {border-top:1px solid red;}
td {border-left:1px solid #000;}
td + td {border-left:1px solid red;}
```

Comment: Since you are setting the border width to 10px, you are simply getting 5px of it inside the cell and 5px outside.

Comment: Um... Then you should use `border-collapse: separate;` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You have already set margin for `td` in css

```
td {
    border-left:1px solid #000;
}
```

So it is going out when you again set it to 10px;

You can add a **div or span** in it to make it work like

***[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/humg4/4/)***

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td><span style="border-left:10px solid blue"><span>Content</td>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td>Content</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td>Content</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td>Content</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Or change it in CSS directly like

```
td {
        border-left:10px solid blue;
    }
```

Or you can simply do

```
table {
    border:1px solid #000;
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
```

instead of

```
 table {
        border:1px solid #000;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        border-spacing: 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try `border-collapse: separate;` instead of   `border-collapse: collapse;`

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
border-collapse: separate;
```

Instead of

```
border-collapse: collapse;
```

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/deepakmanwal/XZdB3/) [DETAILS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-collapse)

Answer (score 0):

That's the intended behavior when you add borders to a table/cell/row.

If I understant correctly, you want a vertical line that is inside the cell, to the left of the text.
If this is the case, you can either add the border to the content using something like:

```
padding-left: 5px;
border-left: 10px;
```

or you can add a span element with 10px width and blue background inside the td

Comment: I should note that the borders are collapsed, which causes the issue.